# Start and stop of mule model

Tags: mule

I need to be able to start and stop all services inside a particular model, My understanding of a model is that it is a logical grouping of services, So I was expecting that when I stop a model from JConsole it will also stop all the services within that model, however this does not happen.  Is there a particular way in which I can achieve the above ?
The reason I need to do this is is that within a single `mule-config` we have different groups of services and we wish to start or stop the group of services independently.

Answer (score 2):

Start with all your services set to `initialState="stopped"`, then turn them on as needed. Here is one way to do that:

```
List<String> modelNames = getEnabledModelNames();

for (String modelName : modelNames) {

    try {
        Collection<Service> services = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupServices();
        for (Service service : services) {
            if (modelName.equals(service.getModel().getName())) {
                service.start();
                logger.debug("service started {}", service.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // throw exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure this has ever worked but be aware that in Mule 3.x, the focus has moved away from using models (ie. flows and configuration patterns are flow-unaware).

On Mule 3.x, what you want to do would better be achieved by splitting your configuration in multiple applications and taking these individual Mule applications down and up independently.

On Mule 2.x, one option would be to introspect your running instance MBeans: you should find MBeans representing your Model, then find MBeans for Services within this Model. From there, you'll be able to start/stop Services.

Comment: We currently use Mule 2.2.1 and the application is on prod and i do not see a upgrade effort in the near future :( , yes what you said is correct it does not work, I wondering why ?, If model is a grouping of services then should not the services be started or stopped when the model is started or stopped ?

Comment: The grouping "model" offers is about sharing common configuration properties, not binding their lifecycle.

Comment: "you should find MBeans representing your Model, then find MBeans for Services within this Model" I did try to investigate this option, however given a model i could not find any API which would give me all the services in a model, is there something like model.getServices() or the similar. `org.mule.module.management.mbean.ModelService` seems to the MBean which exposes the properties of the Model.

Comment: There's http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/2.2.1/apidocs/org/mule/api/registry/MuleRegistry.html#lookupServices(java.lang.String)